# NullPointerException in Jetty 6.x while deploying servlet from an external jar

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jetty

When I was trying out [JMinix](https://code.google.com/p/jminix/) servlet with an embedded Jetty 6.x server, I get the following NullPointerException:

```
[ERROR ]:[2014-01-31 14:31:19,194]:[684929885@qtp-1937268239-2 - /jmx]:[mortbay.log]:/jmx
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:414)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:458)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:322)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Initially I suspected JMinix, however it deploys fine with other containers.

A simple servlet within the project works.  Is this a Jetty problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, i deployed another servlet from a different jar file.  That caused the same exception.  Turns out this is a bug in 6.x versions of Jetty.

I changed to Jetty 9.1 (now an Eclipse project, no more org.mortbay) and the problem disappeared.  Here's the snippet from the pom.xml

Had to add jetty-server and jetty-servlet dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.1.v20140108</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.1.v20140108</version>
</dependency>
```